# Wix Webapplication: How do I add an extension without replacing all existing mappings?

Tags: iis, wix, mapping, windows-2003-webserver, wix-iisextension

I'm trying to add a .plan extension to our IIS 6.0 website through WiX.  I'm using

```
<iis:WebApplicationExtension CheckPath="no" Script="yes" Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" Extension="plan"/>
```

Although this is replacing all of the existing application extensions, which is not the behaviour that we want.  Is there a way to simply add .plan?  We would like to avoid using the  Wildcard if possible as we're not sure how it will affect the rest of the site.  I don't think that APPCMD is available on our 2003 server either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we didn't find a way to do this cleanly using the iis:WebApplicationExtension in WiX.

We found this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2004/12/02/273681.aspx that provides a VBScript for adding ScriptMaps.  We edited the script to only execute the HandleListOps function (with the relevant params) so that we didn't get any issues with WScript.  We then call this from a CustomAction in WiX, with the vbs file added as a Binary file.

We're aware that running vbscript custom actions from within an installer isn't ideal, but luckily we're not distributing the application externally and is only going to be used on an internal website, so the target server environment is reasonably well known.